# How to redirect different users based on roles to different pages using same login page?

Tags: php

I am aware of logging module, but I want to redirect students to different pages, and teachers to different page. I am confused if I should make different databases and a combo box in login page and if statement to select different databases or simply make different login pages or I can do something with sessions.Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the user's type in the db and apply basic logic:

```
if ($user->type === 'student') {
  header('Location: http://example.com/students');
  exit;
}

if ($user->type === 'teacher') {
  header('Location: http://example.com/staff');
  exit;
}
```

Comment: Note that you have to do this before you printing/echoing out anything on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combo-box where user will select whether he is a student or a teacher and also a login form, take the value of the selected option using POST method, authenticate the user,if successfully authenticated then register a session according the choice made, then redirect user to the appropriate page.Registering a session will help you in handling future requests.

Comment: Asking the user for their role seems like a bad idea.

Comment: why it's a bad idea?There'll obviously an authentication mechanism, which will authenticate the user before redirecting him to his account.

Comment: So all I have to do to get access to teacher-only content is check the box that says I'm a teacher? Why ask them for their role if you already have access to it via username/password?

Comment: Of course not, there'll also be a login form, in which user will need to enter his/her username and password.

Comment: what if there're two users with the same username, one is a student and other is a teacher?

Comment: Usernames are usually unique for exactly that reason. Also the reason emails are used as usernames because they're guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Usually, but not always. So in your opinion how this should be done?